How to use boost::connected_components when there is a vertex with no edges?
The example in boost is from the doc
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_85_0/libs/graph/example/connected_components.cpp
//=======================================================================
// Copyright 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000 University of Notre Dame.
// Authors: Andrew Lumsdaine, Lie-Quan Lee, Jeremy G. Siek
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
// accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//=======================================================================

#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>

/*

  This example demonstrates the usage of the connected_components
  algorithm on a undirected graph. The example graphs come from
  "Introduction to Algorithms", Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest p. 87
  (though we number the vertices from zero instead of one).

  Sample output:

  Total number of components: 3
  Vertex 0 is in component 0
  Vertex 1 is in component 0
  Vertex 2 is in component 1
  Vertex 3 is in component 2
  Vertex 4 is in component 0
  Vertex 5 is in component 1

 */

using namespace std;

int main(int , char* []) 
{
  using namespace boost;
  {
    typedef adjacency_list <vecS, vecS, undirectedS> Graph;

    Graph G;
    add_edge(0, 1, G);
    add_edge(1, 4, G);
    add_edge(4, 0, G);
    add_edge(2, 5, G);
    
    std::vector<int> component(num_vertices(G));
    int num = connected_components(G, &component[0]);
    
    std::vector<int>::size_type i;
    cout << "Total number of components: " << num << endl;
    for (i = 0; i != component.size(); ++i)
      cout << "Vertex " << i <<" is in component " << component[i] << endl;
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

This works fine.
https://godbolt.org/z/3jYaEM9Ks
However there is a catch. What about a vertex this is not connected by edges to any other vertex. It should end in a component by itself. However I'm not sure how to change the code to achieve this?
I've tried adding
 add_vertex(6, G);

but that intuition does not work.


However there is a catch. What about a vertex this is not connected by edges to any other vertex. It should end in a component by itself.

In your example, vertex #3 is such a vertex. It is already in its own component. SUCCESS!

I've tried adding add_vertex(6, G); but that intuition does not work.

I have no idea what that should accomplish. You're calling add_vertex with an argument 6 to initialize the vertex properties with. But you have no vertex properties ¯\(ツ)/¯.
If you want to add a vertex, just say auto descriptor = add_vertex(G);. But as you've seen above there is no need because vertex 3 was ALREADY unconnected.
If you meant to make sure that 7 vertices exist (0,1,2,3,4,5,6), just make it so: Live On Coliru
Graph g(7);

Now it prints, as you expected:
Total number of components: 4
Vertex 0 is in component 0
Vertex 1 is in component 0
Vertex 2 is in component 1
Vertex 3 is in component 2
Vertex 4 is in component 0
Vertex 5 is in component 1
Vertex 6 is in component 3

BONUS
If you really are just confused about implicit vertex indices in vecS storage, compare to listS storage:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/connected_components.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int, char*[]) {
    using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS>;
    using VDesc = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

    Graph g;
    std::array<VDesc, 7> vv;
    for (auto& v : vv)
        v = add_vertex(g);

    add_edge(vv[0], vv[1], g);
    add_edge(vv[1], vv[4], g);
    add_edge(vv[4], vv[0], g);
    add_edge(vv[2], vv[5], g);

    std::map<VDesc, int>    component;
    std::map<VDesc, size_t> index;

    auto compmap = boost::make_assoc_property_map(component);
    auto idmap   = boost::make_assoc_property_map(index);

    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        index.emplace(v, index.size());
    int num = connected_components( //
        g,                          //
        compmap,
        boost::vertex_index_map(idmap));

    std::cout << "Total number of components: " << num << std::endl;

    // Iterate vertices
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
        std::cout << "Vertex " << v << " (id " << idmap[v] << ") is in component " << compmap[v] << std::endl;

    // Iterate map
    std::cout << "Total number mappings: " << component.size() << std::endl;
    for (auto const& [v, comp] : component)
        std::cout << "Vertex " << v << " (id " << idmap[v] << ") is in component " << comp << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

Printing e.g.
Total number of components: 4
Vertex 0x504000000050 (id 0) is in component 0
Vertex 0x504000000090 (id 1) is in component 0
Vertex 0x5040000000d0 (id 2) is in component 1
Vertex 0x504000000110 (id 3) is in component 2
Vertex 0x504000000150 (id 4) is in component 0
Vertex 0x504000000190 (id 5) is in component 1
Vertex 0x5040000001d0 (id 6) is in component 3
Total number mappings: 7
Vertex 0x504000000050 (id 0) is in component 0
Vertex 0x504000000090 (id 1) is in component 0
Vertex 0x5040000000d0 (id 2) is in component 1
Vertex 0x504000000110 (id 3) is in component 2
Vertex 0x504000000150 (id 4) is in component 0
Vertex 0x504000000190 (id 5) is in component 1
Vertex 0x5040000001d0 (id 6) is in component 3


Thanks. I didn't notice the vertex 3 and how it behaved and how the implicit vertex indices worked. It's obvious now.

The error in my own code was to not initialize the graph with the number of vertices to start with and in my case I had only one vertex not connected to anything. Initializing the graph as Graph graph(num_verticies) instead of Graph graph solved my actual problem.

Glad I showed several aspects surrounding the problem :) Cheers
